# Resetting an attribute to a default style value in XAML Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a label which looks like this:

```
<Label Style="{StaticResource myStyle}" x:Name="TestLabel">
```

The bound style sets the background color of the label to red color.

Then later on in the code, I do this:

```
TestLabel.SetValue(Label.BackgroundColorProperty, Color.Green);
```

This sets the background color of the label to green.

But then, I need to clear the green color which I set manually, and I need to reset it to the default value, dictated by the bound style (in this case red).

So I do this:

```
TestLabel.ClearValue(Label.BackgroundColorProperty);
```

But instead reverting back to red, the background color gets removed completely and becomes transparent (which is the default setting for a label, without any styles attached to it).

*(One solution that offers itself would be TestLabel.SetValue(Label.BackgroundColorProperty, Color.Red);, but I cannot do this, since I need the color to revert back to whatever the style attached to it says it is, since different labels have different styles attached)*

Comment: Are you using mvvm pattern?

Comment: Why not simply keep track of previous color, and set it when you are trying to reset it. `var color = TestLabel.BackgroundColor; ... TestLabel.BackgroundColor = color;`

Answer (score 0):

The best way to set or reset attribute use trigger instead of manual set.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/triggers/

Comment: I don't really see how could I use the triggers here because I need the color to change  during specific conditions in the code behind, it's not just some simple OnMouseOver event or something like that

Comment: didn't get you. which kind of condition you use? why you use this TestLabel.ClearValue  ? if you want change red color back then set again using this TestLabel.SetValue(Label.BackgroundColorProperty, Color.Red);

Comment: Trigger is based on condition and when value was change it automatically set default color.